# How to serve files through remote host first with fallback to local files when it is down?

Tags: nginx

I've several nginx "clients", which are proxying all requests to location /static/ to remote location http://central/static/, and I have a copy of all files locally as well.

What I want, is to switch to this local copy when remote is not available.

The only option which comes to my mind is to configure set of upstreams where local server will be the last one (with minimal weight), and remote will be with maximal weight.

But, perhaps, there is a bit less complicated way to do this? Using cache is not really an option, as I can never be sure that all files are in cache, and clients (browsers) may choose to disable caching or request fresh copy any time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
location /static {
    proxy_pass http://central/static;
    proxy_next_upstream off;
    root /local/static/files;
}
```

The remote server has to be offline. If it is giving any response ie 404 this won't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work - produces "502 Bad gateway". So I've resorted to defining local server, listening on unix socket and marked it as "backup" in upstream.